# Port representation in kubernetes port list

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I deployed a kubernetes loadbalancer on google cloud.

```
$kubectl expose deployments nginx --port 80 --type LoadBalancer
$kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.31.240.1    <none>        443/TCP        9m
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.31.253.32   35.188.14.5   80:30787/TCP   1m
```

Notice the nginx port has 80 and 30787. What does these two ports mean?

Answer (score 1):

> Notice the nginx port has 80 and 30787. What does these two ports mean?

A `kubectl describe service nginx` would likely be more explanatory, but the tl;dr is that 80 is the port from inside the cluster, and 30787 is the [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) pointing to port 80 of that Service. The `NodePort` is required because in order for whatever load balancer is running on `35.188.14.5` to connect into the cluster, it needs a TCP/IP port that it can use, since it (hopefully!) cannot use `10.31.253.32:80` to otherwise communicate with that Service the way things inside the CNI boundary do.